# How would I be able to delete Survey Invitations

Tags: survey, salesforce-survey

I been testing out sending surveys via emailing on flow, now I have a few testing surveys that isn't needed. And I would like to delete them.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the app Launcher. Search:

****Surveys **->** Click the survey that you would like to delete the Invitations* **->** Related **->** View All for
Survey Invitations.***